# Login with gmail account in Coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, google-api, coldfusion-9, google-signin

I want to login with gmail/google account and I found this tutorial [Gmail Login in Coldfusion](https://github.com/jensbits/Google-Analytics-Data-Export-API-with-ColdFusion). I done All the steps and After login my page redirect then I want to display user Profile information so I dump this

```
<cfdump var="#session.profilesArray#">
```

but it gives me an empty array.why I am not getting my profile data after successfully lo-gin.
If I am getting wrong way for fetching my profile then what is correct way. Thanks.

Comment: dump the entire session scope and see what actually is there.

Comment: My entire session is in `session.profilesArray`. Is it not in this?

Comment: profilesArray is not the entire session scope. `<cfdump var=#session# />`

Comment: yes it display a dump table in which profile aray is empty and one more thing is that `ga_accesstoken` is `Authorization Failed: No Google Analytics profiles associated with account.` what is this

Comment: is `ga.cfc` is correct or any error is in it?

Comment: What is what? It's a self-explanatory error message; check the account details being used.

Comment: I have successfully login with account

Comment: @DanBracuk kindly tell me what is actual problem?

Comment: where can I find my access_token? is it in Application.cfc?

Comment: So presumably profilesArray  only gets created if your login was successful. If ga_accesstoken = Authorization Failed I'm guessing your login was unsuccessful.

Comment: But I login and It ask me to allow to accept it and then I accept and the Page redirect to my URL that i have set. If login was unsuccessful then it should give me some error while login

Comment: Look at the [ga.cfc source code](https://github.com/jensbits/Google-Analytics-Data-Export-API-with-ColdFusion/blob/master/ga.cfc#L144) - the error is not a login one, the error is because the array is empty. Overwriting `session.ga_accessToken` with the error message is bad programming by the author of ga.cfc; try dumping the actual response of `profilesResponse` inside the ga.cfc `parseProfiles` function and seeing what is coming back - it might have a different/better error message.

Comment: it gives some error in var dump

Comment: can someone tell me how can I get access_token and how to solve my problem. I am stuck here plz helm me out to sovle this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just add this line into your `scope`
Open your `Application.cfc` and then add this code
change `scope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly"` with `scope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email+https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile`

you can just add `scope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile` but if u want to access email then add second one as I Post in my answer.

```
     <cfset request.oauthSettings = 
           {scope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email+https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile",
                                    client_id = "Your-id",
                                    client_secret = "your-secret",
                                    redirect_uri = "redirect-page",
                                    state = "optional"} />
```

Now you can get User Information from function that you can call like this

```
    <cfscript>              
        public function getProfile(accesstoken) {

            var h = new com.adobe.coldfusion.http();
            h.setURL("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo");
            h.setMethod("get");
            h.addParam(type="header",name="Authorization",value="OAuth #accesstoken#");
            h.addParam(type="header",name="GData-Version",value="3");
            h.setResolveURL(true);
            var result = h.send().getPrefix();
            return deserializeJSON(result.filecontent.toString());
        }       
    </cfscript>

            <cfoutput>
            <cfset show = getProfile(session.ga_accessToken)>
            <cfdump var="#show#">
           </cfoutput>
```

Hope this will help you.